# Investigate handle count peaks in azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We have (quite large) ASP.Net webforms application using .Net Framework 4.8 running in an azure app service with several instances (scaled out). The application uses a set of azure sql databases and azure blob storage as datastores. We found some interesting peaks in the handle count of the app service. We're seeing several peaks each day. It doesn't seem to be a handle leak, since after the peaks the handle count goes back to its original value. I've been searching the documentation to find a way to troubleshoot where these peaks are coming from, but I'm coming up blank.

I'm looking for ways to identify what is causing these peaks to fix the issue. I assume this is an issue in our software, but I have no idea on how to pinpoint the issue.

- I've already to to correlate the peaks to specific requests using the application insights logging, and seeing if any requests around those times have a very high dependency count, but have not found a pattern.
- It doesn't seem to be an issue with threads, there are no peaks in thread count
- It doesn't seem t be an issue with request counts, there are no peaks in request count

What would be the best way to troubleshoot these peaks?

The max handle count in the last 24 hours (split by instance):
[image: Max handles split by instance]

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the root cause?

Comment: Unfortunately not